# How can i create a UIImage from a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview, uiimage, animated

I am trying to implement an animation set of images on my application.

```
NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage1.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage2.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage3.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage4.gif"],
    nil];

UIImageView *myAnimatedView = [UIImageView alloc];
[myAnimatedView initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
myAnimatedView.animationImages = myImages;
myAnimatedView.animationDuration = 0.25; // seconds
myAnimatedView.animationRepeatCount = 0; // 0 = loops forever
[myAnimatedView startAnimating];
[self addSubview:myAnimatedView];
[myAnimatedView release];
```

Ok, but the problem is that i am using an API function to place a marker on a map.

That function is the following:

```
RMMarker *newMarker;
UIImage *blueMarkerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker.png"];
newMarker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:blueMarkerImage anchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)];


[mapView.contents.markerManager addMarker:newMarker AtLatLong:position];
[newMarker release];
```

The problem is that "initWithUIImage:" only works with UIImage, not with UIImageView.

So, how can i solve it??

**UPDATE:** My new code that is not working:

```
NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:                           
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker0.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker1.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker2.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker3.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker4.png"],
                         nil];

    UIImageView *myAnimatedView = [UIImageView alloc];
    myAnimatedView.animationImages = myImages;
    myAnimatedView.animationDuration = 10; // seconds
    myAnimatedView.animationRepeatCount = 1; // 0 = loops forever
    [myAnimatedView startAnimating];
    RMMarker *newMarker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:[myAnimatedView image] anchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)];
    [mapView.contents.markerManager addMarker:newMarker AtLatLong:markerPosition];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `image` message from `UIImageView`:

```
 newMarker = 
     [
          [RMMarker alloc] 
              initWithUIImage:[myAnimatedView image] 
              anchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)
     ];
```

Or, if what you need is creating a `UIImageView` then you can try:

```
 UIImageView *newMakerImageView = 
     [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
        [
          [RMMarker alloc] 
              initWithUIImage:yourImageHere
              anchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)
        ]
     ];
```

Comment: with the first implementation it doesn't shows anything. I have updated the ask, so you can see my new code

Comment: The problem about what you suggested, is that [myAnimatedView image] is not returning anything, it should be [myAnimatedView animationImages], but i get again the same incompatibility warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *myAnimatedView = [UIImageView alloc]
```

That may just be a copy/paste error, but you forget the init.

```
UIImageView *myAnimatedView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[self bounds]] autorelease]
```